# UIImageView in UIScrollView, zooming is jittery

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have a UIImageView in a UIScrollview. I used the instructions in Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html).

I set minimum and maximum zoom scales. (0.5 and 6.0). I set the delegate to self.

I returned the image view in viewForZoomingInScrollView. However I don't know what to do in scrollViewDidEndZooming.

The result I am having is a jittery zoom and not consistent. It is just not behaving like the photo gallery app.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution that I found to work flawless. It includes double tap and two finger gestures to zoom in and out. http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Accept your answer so that it'll help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
//create imageview with pinchGesture

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(17, 95, 285, 130);
        myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picture]];
        myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
        pgr.delegate = self;
        [myImage addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
        [scrollview addSubview:myImage];
```

// handlepinch: method

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
 recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform,   recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

Before that add  in .h file

Hope it will useful for you...

Comment: The zoom works smoothly but the image sometimes runs beyond to the right which I think is because of scrollView's pan. The pan sometimes interferes with the zoom and the pan decreases as I zoom in more. Should I eliminate scrollview altogether and implement pan gesture on imageview? In any case is there a way to make it behave just like the photo app on ios? Thanks

Comment: You can also set maximum and minimum scale properties for scrollview for more information check this [click here](http://navaneethant.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/zooming-and-scrolling-in-uiscrollviewiphone-application/)

Answer (score 1):

Set your ImageView scaling contentMode to be UIViewContentModeCenter and zoom out (if needed) on load. Set the starting zoom scale when you have the image ready by doing something like this :

```
        //Min scale is how much ever it takes to fit the image in the view
        CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
        CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.width;
        CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.imageView.image.size.height;
        CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. I was using contentMode scale to fit which was causing jittery effect.